# blueimp JQuery plugin custom users dirs usage

Tags: php, jquery, download, blueimp, userid

I have UploadHandler class with parameters and constructor:

```
    function __construct($profile_id, $options = null, $initialize = true, $error_messages = null) {
    $this->response = array();
    $this->options = array(
        'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/'.basename($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_NAME')),
        'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/files/'.$profile_id.'/', //'.$this->options['profile_id'].'/',
        'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/files/'.$profile_id.'/', //.$profile_id.'/' ---'.$this->options['profile_id'].'/',
        'input_stream' => 'php://input',
```

My $profile_id is ID of users profile.
This value placed as hidden value in file upload form.
Then file upload is done I have my file in directory - specified to user by profile_id.

But if I need to see existing files for user Plugin doing scan of root 'server/php/' directory.

Ok. In time of writing this post my case is going work good. Please read following to add users dir on download moments.

1. In this case you need switch POST/GET variable in server/php/index.php:

   ```
   if(isset($_POST['profile_id'])) {
   $profile_id = $_POST['profile_id'];}
   ```

   if(isset($_GET['profile_id'])) {
       $profile_id = $_GET['profile_id'];
      }
2. Put $profile_id in class(index.php):

   $upload_handler = new CustomUploadHandler(**$profile_id**, $options);
3. Modify main.js of blueimp from line 58(replace by following code):

   ```
   } else {
   // Load existing files:
   $('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');
   //var profile_id = Session["profile_id"];
   //var profile_id = oForm.elements["profile_id"].value;
   //var ee = $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url');
   var form = $("#fileupload");
   var profile_id = $("[name='profile_id']", form).val();
   //alert(ee);
   //alert(profile_id);
   $.ajax({
       // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
       //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
       url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url') +'?profile_id='+profile_id,
       //url: 'server/php/files/'+profile_id +'/',
       dataType: 'json',
       context: $('#fileupload')[0]
   }).always(function () {
       $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
   }).done(function (result) {
       $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
           .call(this, $.Event('done'), {result: result});
   });
   ```

   }
4. You need to have hidden input with your user (ID,XX,TTT) in #fileupload:
5. Enjoy!

Comment: I'm confused - are you both presenting a possible coding scenario and answering it yourself? What is your question?

Comment: I have found answer on my question during create this case.